# Tkinter GUI many entry widgets, is there a better way?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to collect data for a database inside my tool. At the moment I have only a few variables so I have some entry widgets where the user puts the data in.

So now if I think a bit further I may have 25 or more variables. But I don't want to overflow my GUI with 25 or more entry widgets.

I hope its okay to not include any code, I think entry widgets are well known.

So my question is:
Is there a better widget to collect many inputs? I tried it with a treeview but I cant find a way to make the cells editable or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have one entry field and next to it a dropdown menu with which the user specifies which data he is entering.

If you can categorize the inputs, you could look into notebooks/tabs for tkinter to seperate them nicely.

Comment: I also thought about notebooks/tabs, but I also want to reduce the amount of code I need to do this. So I try to look in many ways to do this!

Comment: For least amount of Code, probably the entry field with combobox to select which value is entered.

Comment: If you need to go through all variables, you could do this also with one entry widget, have him enter the first value, a button called next and with that clear the entry widget and let him enter the next value.

Comment: I see, but I think this could be a bit user unfriendly. Is'nt there a way to have a listbox with two columns? Left column shows all the variable names and the right column is an entry field?

Comment: You could put two listboxes next to each other.

Comment: You could also put a listbox next to an entry field, that is as high as the listbox and treat every line as an entry to the corresponding entry in the listbox.

Comment: I will try this! Thanks for the nice discussion!